# Delete last cell in uitableview from button swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a accept and deny button on my tableview cell. When the user clicks the deny button it deletes the data from parse as well as the reloads the table. However, when I get to the final request, hitting deny deletes the data from Parse but the cell doesn't disappear.

For context
I have a PFObject Array called `var requests = [PFObject]()`

Here is my code for the button

In my `cellForRowIndexPath`

```
 cell.declineBtn.addTarget(self, action: "declineRequest:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Then I implement the function `declineRequest`

```
func declineRequest(sender: UIButton) {
    var cell: NotificationsTableViewCell = sender.superview!.superview as! NotificationsTableViewCell 

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(cell.center)!

    let innerP1 = NSPredicate(format: "sender = %@ AND postId = %@ ", cell.requesterEmailLabel.text! , cell.postIdLabel.text!)

    var innerQ1: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Requests", predicate: innerP1)
    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([innerQ1])

    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{
         (object:AnyObject? , error:NSError?) -> Void in
          if(error == nil){
          object!.deleteInBackground(); 
          loadNotifications(); // self.tableView.reloadData() is in this call
      }
    }
  }                   
}
```

I need to somehow tell the table that the array of data is empty. 
Let me know if I need to add more context. I am not trying to use the `commitEditingStyle editingStyle`, instead I want the button to take care of the deletions.

**EDIT #2**  
After trying to delete in background with block the data still gets deleted but the table view still doesnt delete the last row remaining in the table view.

Here is the code

```
 query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{
         (object:AnyObject? , error:NSError?) -> Void in
          if(error == nil){
            object!.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock {(success: Bool, error: NSError?)-> Void in
            if (success) {
                self.loadNotifications()

                println("Load Notifications")
            }
            else {
                println("cannot delete")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the solution, this works for me. the key was to add the following code.

```
    self.requests.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    self.notificationImages.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Where requests, and notificationImages are both arrays where I store request information, and the other user images. Once I remove them at the index path it doesnt fail on the last cell.

```
func declineRequest(sender: UIButton) {
    var cell: NotificationsTableViewCell = sender.superview!.superview as! NotificationsTableViewCell
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(cell.center)!
    let innerP1 = NSPredicate(format: "sender = %@ AND postId = %@ ", cell.requesterEmailLabel.text! , cell.postIdLabel.text!)
    var innerQ1: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Requests", predicate: innerP1)
    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([innerQ1])
    self.requests.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    self.notificationImages.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
        query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (object:AnyObject? , error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if(error == nil){
                object!.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock {(success: Bool, error: NSError?)-> Void in
                    if (success) {
                        println("request deleted")

                    }
                    else {
                        println("cannot delete")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you verified that your db deletion itself works outside of the tableview context I suspect racing conditions, i.e. deletion is asynchronous (`object!.deleteInBackground();`) and the reload appears immediately after submitting the query to the parse backend, thus faster than the commission of the deletion transaction.

Consider using `– deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:` (https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:).
This way a callback will be invoked once the query was (un-)successfully executed facilitating an effective reload.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a completion block while you delete, as your table view reload is occurring in main thread and the deletion is occurring in background thread which can cause a delay due to network latency , this is reason which causing the cell to be there after you delete.

Yeah this code is in objective C, as I am not so well versed with Swift :-

```
[object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            //reload data now
           }
```

Comment: so it i did have a object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock which I replaced with object!.deleteInBackground() but I had the same issue , do you mean for the block to be outside the getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock? or inside of it? Do i need to find the object first then delete it ? or can I do query.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock right away?

Comment: I mean inside getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock , once error is nil then call  [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock with completion handler, inside that completion handler reload the data.

Comment: Okay ill try this again, i have tried this before , if it doesnt work ill update my source code! and let you know

Comment: Vizllx it still doesnt work for me, it deletes all the other rows the same but on the remaining row it does not dissappear like the rest